# Scheduling background work in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, intentservice

I'm new to Android so I want to make sure that the following solution is the correct one.

The problem: 
I want to sync the device's local database with a database on my server, via a webservice, every 10 minutes. I already have a web service call that I can make that returns the new/updated records. What I'm wondering is what is the best way to schedule this task. I want the databases to sync even when the application is not running.

My solution (is this the correct route to go?):
I will have one BroadcastReceiver that listens for android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED, in it's onReceive I will create an AlarmManager that sends a message to MyReceiver (via a PendingIntent) every 10 minutes. Also, in my application's startup I will do the same (create an alarm to send messages to the MyReceiver via a PendingIntent) - Since both alarms are sending messages to MyReceiver and their corresponding PendingIntents are initialized with PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT will the new alarm override the old one? (this is what I want to do, in case for some reason the alarm gets cancelled after device boot it should be restarted when the application starts).

In MyReceiver's onReceive() I will create a MyIntentService (this instance will make the webservice call and update the local database).

Is this a good solution? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solution is fine...Actually all the AlarmManager instances get cleared when device turned off and rebooted.

The simple way is that...
First create AlarmManager when application started.
Second in onReceive of BOOT_COMPLETED BroadcastReceiver.

Its enough, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT will make sure of having only one activated alarm at a time.

In this way, alarm registered when your application started. There will be no issue if its already registered via BOOT_COMPLETED. Activated alarm will deactivated when you turn off your device, but BroadcastReceiver to BOOT_COMPLETED will take care of registration new alarm at next boot.

If you decide that this answers your question, please mark it as "accepted". This will raise both your and my reputation score.

Also you need to review your interval to use network, it might be very resource consuming for device and user. One policy might be to have longer period of interval and check for update when user starts your app (this might not be user friendly but can save many system resources and battery power as well). Try to find some better policy according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Using FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT in that manner will override the existing PendingIntent if one exists. I'm not positive but I believe that as soon as you get into onReceive, the PendingIntent is consumed so it's no longer there to be overridden.   In either case, it sounds like this is the functionality you are looking for and yes it's a good way to solve this kind of problem.  My only other suggestion would be if the 10 minute interval timing is not absolutely critical then use one of the INTERVAL_ schedules (INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES for example) in your AlarmManager to help conserve battery life; basically it lets allows all apps that run on intervals to "batch" their work together and wake the device up less frequently.